# parsing JSON column in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a JSON string stored in a SQL Server table column.  The column is named MSSG_RECIPS and contains one long text string like:

```
`{"type":"email","recipient":"\"Artzer, Daniel J\" <DJArtzer@emailaddr.com>","sentTS":"2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z"},{"type":"email","recipient":"\"Friedman, Brian\" <BFriedman@emailaddr.com>","sentTS":"2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z"},{"type":"email","recipient":"\"Higgins, Laura L\" <LLHiggins@emailaddr.com>","sentTS":"2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z"},{"type":"email","recipient":"\"Landenberger, Dan R\" <DRLandenberger@emailaddr.com>","sentTS":"2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z"},{"type":"email","recipient":"\"Leitl, Scott\" <SLeitl@emailaddr.com>","sentTS":"2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z"},{"type":"email","recipient":"\"Mendoza, Mario\" <MMendoza@emailaddr.com>","sentTS":"2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z"}`
```

This sample string illustrates the format of my JSON, each element being comma-separated.

I am able to parse this 2 ways.  One, using JSON_VALUE, I can retrieve the attributes as individual columns:

```
select
 JSON_VALUE(mssg_recips, '$.type'),
 JSON_VALUE(mssg_recips, '$.recipient'),
 JSON_VALUE(mssg_recips, '$.sentTS'),
 DOC_ID
from MY_JSON_TAB
```

However, this only returns the 1st element of the JSON.

The other method I tried is:

```
select doc_id, value as EMAIL_RECIP
from MY_JSON_TAB
Cross Apply OPENJSON(MSSG_RECIPS)
```

This returned the record as rows instead of columns but, again, only the 1st element.

How do I traverse downward, so to speak, to retrieve the 2nd, 3rd, and so on elements?

Comment: See that green checkmark in the answer below? It's calling for you ;)

Answer (score 7):

[JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql) returns a single scalar value. For an array of a nested JSON objects you can use [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql).

When using `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON() WITH( ...)` you need to specify the properties of the JSON array you want to draw out e.g.

```
select id, recipient, sentTS
from my_json_tab
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(my_json) WITH(
       recipient varchar(200)
     , sentTS varchar(60)
     ) as my_json_array

+----+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| id |                 recipient                 |          sentTS          |
+----+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | "AAAA, Daniel J" <DJArtzer@emailaddr.com> | 2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z |
|  1 | "BBBB, Brian" <BFriedman@emailaddr.com>   | 2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z |
|  1 | "CCCC, Laura L" <LLHiggins@emailaddr.com> | 2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z |
|  2 | "xxxx, Daniel J" <DJArtzer@emailaddr.com> | 2017-11-08T20:58:14.600Z |
+----+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

NB: When storing multi-element JSON you need to contain the entire JSON within [ ]

In the example result ID=1 has [ json-here ]  but id=2 does not, notice the difference in outcome. All element of ID=1 are returned, but that is not true for id=2.

See this *[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cd7046ebdb77505a41ab07b2bfcb6f5f)* for a live demo of the example above.

> OPENJSON is a table-valued function that parses JSON text and returns
>   objects and properties from the JSON input as rows and columns. In
>   other words, OPENJSON provides a rowset view over a JSON document. You
>   can explicitly specify the columns in the rowset and the JSON property
>   paths used to populate the columns. Since OPENJSON returns a set of
>   rows, you can use OPENJSON in the FROM clause of a Transact-SQL
>   statement just as you can use any other table, view, or table-valued
>   function.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql

Comment: Clearly, I am still doing something wrong.  Applying ISJSON to each record returns 1 for all non-null entries.  So far, so good.  However,  JSON_QUERY still returns all NULLs:

    select distinct
     PAYLOAD_LINE_SEG,
     JSON_QUERY(PAYLOAD_LINE_SEG,'$.pipeDiameter') as pipe_info
    from SYSTEM_BLOWDOWNS

returns:
[{"lineName":"AQ46-5","pipeDiameter":"10","pipeLength":"15620","pressure":"75","duration":"no","volume":"158"}]   NULL

What am I missing?

Comment: No, my question is not completely resolved.  I tried to provide a sample from my JSON Table column, along with my JSON_QUERY syntax in my previous comment.  I still cannot seem to get JSON_QUERY to work and I don't understand why not.
Thank you!

Comment: I upvoted your answer. This was exactly what I was trying to figure out, thanks for the fiddle!

Comment: (re comment back in Nov 13 2017) Use OPENJSON in the `from` clause and NOT the `select` clause (as the documentation snippet seen above states) plus if there is more than one "row" in the JSON to be returned then also use `cross apply` or `outer apply` to permit those multiple rows to be returned. see this updated https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ab01bd2f550ccf86943d7ebf4fedd614