# parse json as part of pd.read_sql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I use this (improvement suggestions very welcome):

```
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("bla")

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))

with engine.connect() as con:

    sql_df = pd.read_sql(
            "SELECT TOP 10 json_column, id FROM SomeTable;",
            con=engine
    )
```

I end up with a pandas df with 2 columns one of which is json:

```
{\r\n"c1":1,\r\n"c2":42}
```

Is there a way to parse this during pd.read_sql to end up with 3 columns like so:

```
c1, c2, id
```

Comment: this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211526/parsing-json-column-in-sql-server

Comment: Good point - doing it in sql,